# Cannot echo php in html page

Tags: php, html, echo

I have a little problem on the simple echo of php.

Here is my code

```
<body>
welcome to new page <?php echo "1234"; ?> !!!!!
</body>
```

But the output only show : welcome to new page !!!!!

And in the inspect element, the php part has been commented

```
<body>
welcome to new page 
<!--?php echo "1234"; ?-->
 !!!!!
</body>
```

why?

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: What URL are you using to access the script? You need to load the script via the web server configured to parse PHP scripts

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a server configuration problem, not a programming error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check to see that the file ends with `.php`
2. Check that PHP is installed on your server.

Create a new file called `new_file.php`

Add this code to your file:

```
<?php echo PHP_VERSION; ?>
```

If you get a blank white page, then something is messed up with your server, and you need to further debug the server.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, but both are checked and same problems appear. Any other possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Many (maybe most, all?) webservers aren't configured to look for php script inside html files out of the box.

In case you are using .html extension for your file, it's good practice to just stick to .php files for your php script and you can HTML code in it.

Other option is to configure Apache to run php script inside html file.

Doing this is pretty simple: open up your favorite text editor, throw this line in there:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

and save it as `.htaccess` in the same folder as your .html file. And that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

weclome
<?php 


echo "123";



 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

just save file with .php extension and you are good to go..!